# Смена конфигурации при чтении nfc- метки

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

При смене конфигурации устройства, например, при переходе из портретной ориентации в горизонтальную, Android создаёт новый экземпляр активити, используя тот же `Intent`, который использовался для создания исходного экземпляра:

```
Android creates a brand new instance of the same activity class, using the
same Intent that was used to create the original instance
```

А как лучше обрабатывать смену конфигурации, если `Intent`, который использовался для создания исходного экземпляра, - `Intent` обнаружения nfc- метки, например, `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED`? Я хочу, чтобы при смене конфигурации обмен сообщениями с меткой продолжался, не создавался новый экземпляр метки. Возможно ли это сделать без запрета смены конфигурации? Например, чтобы layout активити заменился на новый, а экземпляр метки остался старым. Где в таком случае лучше хранить метку?